# Custom font Text-View in listvliew in android

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

hi friends i want custom font in my list-view and i using a  custom adapter for this but its not working.Can any one help me out.

```
    { 
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        Typeface customfont = f1.showf();
        holder.txtViewTitle.setTypeface(customfont);
        holder.txtViewDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
```

f1.show code:-

```
    public Typeface showf()
    {             
         final AssetManager assets = this.getAssets();
         final Typeface tvFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(assets, "Monlam Uni OuChan2.ttf");

         return tvFont;
    }
```

Comment: show your holder class?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the fact that you have spaces in your file names isn't preventing the program from properly recognizing the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing/refactoring

**Monlam Uni OuChan2.ttf**

to

**monlam_uni_ouchan2.ttf**

Answer (score 0):

You can Have this in CustomListAdapter Class

```
private class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private int id;
private List <String>items ;

public CustomListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId , List<String> list ) 
{
    super(context, textViewResourceId, list);           
    mContext = context;
    id = textViewResourceId;
    items = list ;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View mView = v ;
    if(mView == null){
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mView = vi.inflate(id, null);
    }

    TextView text = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

    if(items.get(position) != null )
    {
        text.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        text.setText(items.get(position));
        text.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); 
        int color = Color.argb( 200, 255, 64, 64 );
            text.setBackgroundColor( color );

    }

    return mView;
}
```

}

And Custom_xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView  
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:id="@+id/textView"
 android:textSize="20px" 
 android:paddingTop="10dip"       
 android:paddingBottom="10dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add extra details and more logging?

Also make sure that your file is in Assets folder. Don't just add it yourself, use File>New>Folder>Assets Folder as shown in image below. As Adam pointed out, you may also try escaping space characters.

[image: Adding assets folder]

Answer (score 0):

Custom Font class

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

    public CustomTextView (Context context) {
        super(context);

        applyCustomFont(context);
    }

    public CustomTextView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        applyCustomFont(context);
    }

    public CustomTextView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        applyCustomFont(context);
    }

    private void applyCustomFont(Context context) {
        Typeface customFont = FontCache.getTypeface("SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf", context);
        setTypeface(customFont);
    }
}
```

list_item_xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/itemContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.you.package.views.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/green_dark"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Sample text"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In your adapter view holder

```
 public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private RelativeLayout itemContainer;
        private final CustomTextView itemActName;
        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            itemContainer = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.itemContainer);
            itemActName = (CustomTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        }
    }

 @Override
    public CustomAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item_xml, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.itemActName.setText(List.get(position).getText());
        holder.itemContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (mItemClickListener != null) {
                    mItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, position);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/abc.ttf");
    textView.setTypeface(tf);
```

You need to put context of the activity before `getAssets()`

I mean instead of this:

```
      final AssetManager assets = this.getAssets();
```

use

```
      Context context;
      final AssetManager assets = context.getAssets();
```

Answer (score 0):

Where did you put your font? I can see the file name contain white blank and this may caused you problems.
I have another way for you to do this.
Create a custom TextView class like below:

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/MavenPro-Regular.ttf"); // make sure your font is put on assets/font location.
            setTypeface(tf);
        }
    }
}
```

And then just use it from XML like:

```
<yourPackageName.MyTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:text="REGULAR"
            android:textColor="#868688"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont add font again and again add once when view is `null` only once in `getView()`.

First add font in assest folder as shown in image.

[image]

This hierarchy will became path "assests/fonts/bohema.otf"

```
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.font_lv_item, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.font_title_txt);
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/bohema.otf");
            holder.title.setTypeface(tf );

            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        Fonts item = data.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(item.getTile());
        holder.title.setTypeface(item.getTf());

        return row;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Move this line Typeface customfont = f1.showf(); to constructor of the adapter and set font only once in ui component when convertView is null. Hope it will work.

:)GlbMP